# Does anyone know how to display data from a sharepoint list as an image?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions, spfx-tooling, spfx-custom-property-pane

Does anyone know how to display data from a SharePoint list as an image ? I  want for an example each row from the SharePoint list to display as an image to the hub site . For examples i have 5 custom people in my list ,with name job description and mobile phone. I don't want to display the data as a data table .I want each person to be show as an image with his credentials or as persona card .I want a SharePoint solution and I'm really new to SharePoint framework developing.

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately, I'm not sure what you're asking for. Are you wanting to display an image that's stored in an Image column in a list or show an image for a picture column or something else entirely? Really not sure what "display as an image to the hub site means". If you could edit your question to provide additional detail on what you're trying to accomplish, what you've tried, and any errors or roadblocks you've run into, that would be a huge help to getting you some answers. Thanks!

Comment: @Pambos, do you know the basics of react? Or you are looking for a JavaScript-only option?

Comment: @theChrisKent hello thanks for helping me , the thing is that i have a sharepoint list we 3-4 people ,like a custom directory ,every person has a title , a job and telephone.I want  a spfx solution that wil lget that data from sharepoint list and display it to hub site as a card or image,for example like hover card or persona card does .

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov well to be honest this is the first time that i came across with react and I'm not to good with JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

To implement this webpart, you will need:

- [Setup Dev environment for SPFx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment)
- Create a SharePoint list for storing data.
- Create a new SPFx project or take an existing one as a sample. [You can start from this people search SPFx webpart](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-people-directory).
- To get SharePoint list items, you can use a [PnP js library](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-list-items-using-pnp-js-in-spfx/).
- To render items on the screen, you can use [Persona control](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/persona) and [DetailsList](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/detailslist)

**Study materials**

- [What is npm? In 2 minutes - npm tutorial for beginners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNbFagCBlwo)
- [Gulp (Gulp.js) Tutorial for Beginners - 1 - Download and Installing npm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CxM1RYnCYwM)
- [ES6 Tutorial: Learn Modern JavaScript in 1 Hour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCwa_xi0Uuc)
- [JavaScript Async Await](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_Kr9OSfDeU)
- [JavaScript ES6 Arrow Functions Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h33Srr5J9nY)
- [TypeScript Course for Beginners 2021 - Learn TypeScript from Scratch!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BwuLxPH8IDs)
- [React Typescript Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5iWr6Srsj8)
- [Get started with the SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/sharepoint-spfx-get-started/)
- [SharePoint Framework Tutorial 1 - HelloWorld WebPart](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_O2Re5uRLoo)